# Inheritance and navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have such relations:

```
class FirstParent {
   public SecondParent SecondRecord { get; set; }
}

class SecondParent {
   public IEnumerable<FirstParent> FirstRecords { get; set; }
}

class FirstChild1 : FirstParent {
   public String StrInFirstChild1{ get; set; }
}

class SecondChild1 : SecondParent {
   public String StrInSecondChild1{ get; set; }
}

class FirstChild2 : FirstParent {
   public String StrInFirstChild2{ get; set; }
}

class SecondChild2 : SecondParent {
   public String StrInSecondChild2{ get; set; }
}
```

Records related to class FirstChild1 are of type SecondChild1.
Records related to class FirstChild2 are of type SecondChild2.

When I write

```
var record = from ch in context.FirstParent.OfType<FirstChild1>() select ch.SecondRecord;
```

in result I also have SecondParent object. 
What is happening? How to load SecondChild1 objects?

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with that. You're asking for items from the FirstParent entity set which are of type FirstChild1 (I assume that is a subset). And then on each of those you access the navigation property SecondRecord, which is of type SecondParent. So I would expect the query to return just SecondParent typed instances. Maybe if you describe the intent of the query you want to right it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution. I load records from all four tables and do join to collect needed information to anonymous object.